# User privileges and access checks using php sessions

Tags: php, html, session-storage

I want to know if sessionStorage of HTML5 will help me with the following scenario:

I am trying to implement a check on my web portal to see if a page is being accessed by a logged in user or not. so i need at the top of each page to perform a check and avoid session mixture if multiple tabs open the same service. The scenario being: i am logged in to my system using a user with specific privileges (these privileges are recognized using php session variables), my service would be such that different users will use the same browser different tabs to access it, so if another tab is opened and admin tries to log in while another user is logged in then it becomes a mess with php session variables as the privileges access resrictions gets mixed up :)

If sessionStorage is not for me i would appreciate if you suggest any other work around for this.

THANKS YOU

Comment: Users using the same browser with their own tab, with differing levels of accessibility sounds like a security nightmare to me.

Comment: to me as well but this is what the clients wants :)

Comment: It has some kind of a risk as sessionStorage is easily modifiable by anyone as it's client-side. Never do something with login or permissions etc. with Javascript.